# Reverting changes made during the transaction without throwing an exception

Tags: solidity, exceptions

It's not possible to have custom exception messages with `throw`, is there a way to somehow find out which `throw` statement was executed (i.e. code line number)?

Another approach I'm considering is to return `errorCode` instead of using `throw`. Is there a way to reliably revert changes made during the transaction without throwing an exception?

```
contract FirstContract {

    bool isOne;
    bool isTwo;
    bool isThree;

    function foo(bytes32 _value) returns (uint errorCode) {

        if (!isOne) return 101;
        if (!isTwo) return 102;
        if (!isThree) return 103;

        if (SecondContract("0x222").bar(_value) != 0) return 201;

        // 'value' in SecondContract("0x222") was already updated
        // but if further call returns an error, previous changes
        // needs to be reverted

        if (ThirdContract("0x333").baz(_value) != 0) return 301;

        return 0;
    }
}

contract SecondContract {

    uint num;
    bytes32 value;

    function bar(bytes32 _value) returns (uint errorCode) {
        if (num < 10) return 1;
        value = _value;
        return 0;
    }
}

contract ThirdContract {

    bool isActive;
    bytes32 value;

    function baz(bytes32 _value) returns (uint errorCode) {
        if (!isActive) return 1;
        value = _value;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great question! But I'm afraid this is not possible, short of tracking all state transitions manually.